# Handling Google clientLogin Captcha Example

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a desktop application.

I try to perform authentication using

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

However, whenever I get a Captcha challenge, I use a HTTP GET request (I test using web browser) to get the image to present to user.

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Captcha?ctoken=Y-DrsDJRiWNOP3gR7fq0PAq4Yxvi3UXewu7P7jgAKjk0eZKQ358nbh27-JZ3-nlzXvfKOD3JvZNXwmlRunyz8jPKzqmkOLw2LYb3ZWjg-tE%3A0gMUFttsSH7QwganSJd1aw
```

However, I always get the images :

> Sorry, we are unable to handle your
>   request at this time. Please try again
>   later.

Any idea what I had did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why is this tagged app-engine?

Comment: Sorry. Because my app are running on app-engine :p This make me just tag as app-engine without much thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved the problem, please refer to code

http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java?revision=1.86&view=markup (See getCapchaRespond method)

http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/Cloud/src/java/org/shuwnyuan/cloud/Authenticate.java?revision=1.2&view=markup